# Detect obstacle using Raycast

Tags: unity-game-engine, synchronization, raycasting

The logic is , if the Car finds any obstacle using Raycast a function will rotate the angle of a wheel so that car goes left or right. But it seem the car stuck in a certain place where Raycast finds a obstacle , the function WillColllide() returns true,false,true,false sequentially

```
var willColliedVar:boolean;

function WillColllide():boolean{
    var hit:RaycastHit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(distenceDitactorFl.transform.position,distenceDitactorFl.transform.forward,hit) && hit.collider.tag =="wall") {
        var hitDistence = Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.distance);
        if(hitDistence >=4 && hitDistence<=5){      
            return true;    
        }
    }
    if (Physics.Raycast(distenceDitactorFr.transform.position,distenceDitactorFr.transform.forward,hit, 5) && hit.collider.tag =="wall") {
        var hitDistence2 = Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.distance);
        if(hitDistence2 >=4 && hitDistence2<=5){
            return true;    
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function MoveForward():void{
    wheelRr.motorTorque = maxTorque * 0.25;
    wheelRl.motorTorque = maxTorque *0.25;
}
function TurnStraight():void{
    wheelFl.steerAngle = 0;
    wheelFr.steerAngle = 0;
}

function TurnLeft(steerAngle:int):void{
    wheelFl.steerAngle = -steerAngle;
    wheelFr.steerAngle = -steerAngle;
}
function Update () {
    MoveForward();
    if(willColliedVar){
        TurnRight(steerRotationLow);
    }else{
        TurnStraight();
    }
}
function LateUpdate () {

}
function FixedUpdate(){
    willColliedVar = WillColllide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use '5' when trying to pass reference to layer '5', you are actually passing reference to multiple layers (3 and 1), instead you have to put `int layerMask = 1<<5;` then pass in `layerMask` instead of 5. Use `int layerMask = 1<<5;` then `layerMask = ~layerMask;` for everything *except* layer 5.